# Отображение процесса происходящего внутри функции

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Не знаю как точно сформулировать вопрос.

Есть функция, которая выполняет какие-то действия. Она находится в "библиотеке классов". Я подключаю эту библиотеку к своему приложению. Запускаю эту функцию и хочу, чтобы в `ProgressBar` отображался ход выполнения этой процедуры из библиотеки. Как это правильно реализовать в подходе MVVM?

**UPD:** Вот пример по методу Vlad:
Функция в библиотеке:

```
using System;

namespace ClassLib
{
    public static class Service
    {
        public static void Foo(IProgress<int> progress)
        {
            progress.Report(1);    
            string s;
            for (int i = 1; i <= 99; i++)
            {                    
                for (int j = 0; j <= 50000; j++)
                     s = j.ToString();                    
                progress.Report(i);
            }    
            progress.Report(100);
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _progr;
        public int Progress {
            get { return _progr; }
            set { _progr = value;OnPropertyChanged("Progress"); } }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name) =>            
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));            


        public void StartFoo()
        {
            Service.Foo(new Progress<int>(persent => Progress = persent));
        }

    }
```

View:
XAML

```
<Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel x:Name="windowVM"/>
    </Window.DataContext>
...
<ProgressBar Value="{Binding Progress, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

c# code:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindowViewModel vm = (MainWindowViewModel)this.DataContext;
    vm.StartFoo();
}
```

Процесс отображается так : 0 пауза 100 %.

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал в следующее:

1.В библиотечный метод добавить параметр типа [IProgress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
public class Service
{
    public void Foo(IProgress<int> progress)
    {
        progress.Report(1);
        DoSomeWork();
        progress.Report(100);
    }
}
```

2.В модель представления добавить свойство Progress и обработчик изменения прогресса

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public int Progress { get; set; } // при установке значения вызывает PropertyChanged

    private void HandleProgressChanged(int progress)
    {
        Progress = progress;
    }

    private void StartFoo()
    {
        Service.Foo(new Progress<int>(HandleProgressChanged));
    }
}
```

3.В представлении привязаться к свойству Progress.

```
<ProgressBar Progress="{Binding Progress, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

**UPD**

Ну да. Я слишком упростил пример. Ваш код синхронный. Он выполняется в UI-потоке. Поэтому подвисает интерфейс окна. Его нужно запускать асинхронно: сделать библиотечный метод async или запускать его через Task.Run. Например, так:

```
public static async Task Foo(IProgress<int> progress)
{
    progress.Report(1);    
    string s;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 99; i++)
    {                    
        for (int j = 0; j <= 50000; j++)
             s = j.ToString();   
        await Task.Delay(1);// это просто имитация бурной деятельности                                  
        progress.Report(i);
    }    
    progress.Report(100);
}

public async Task StartFoo()
{
    await Service.Foo(new Progress<int>(persent => Progress = persent));
}

private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindowViewModel vm = (MainWindowViewModel)this.DataContext;
    await vm.StartFoo();
}
```

Еще я бы посоветовал использовать команды, а не обработчики нажатия кнопок.

Comment: В качестве дополнительного плюса `Progress<Т>` доставляет сообщения в UI-потоке, независимо от того, в каком потоке они были отправлены.

Comment: Не отображает процесс. Сразу 0 пауза 100.

Comment: @MaximK, добавьте код в вопрос, что ли.

Comment: На счет кнопки, я тоже упростил =)

Comment: @MaximK, ok :) Так работает? Кстати, вот [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/dn630647.aspx) неплохая шпаргалка для создания асинхронных команд с описанием граблей, на которые можно наступить.

Comment: работает... Сейчас в своем проекте проверю