# Обновление пользовательского интерфейса в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Здравствуйте,
Такая заморочка с этим байндингом - уже неделю сижу и не могу понять, что я делаю не так и как надо правильно.

**Дано**:
Есть интерфейс, на нем 3 графика.
При нажатии на один из пунктов меню:

**Должно быть**:

- Во время всей работы, GUI не блокируется и пользователь может в любой момент остановить тест.
- Изменяются надписи на графиках.
- Программа отсылает данные на удаленное устройство и получает статусы.
- Когда программа получает правильные статусы, она должна показать найденные точки на графиках.
- После того, как все нужные данные отправлены и все статусы получены и показаны пользователю, программа вычисляет параметры для каждой из полученных точек. После этого:
  -- Надписи на графиках меняются, графики очищаются и вычесленные параметры (точки) появляются на этих графиках.

**Что получается**:

- Все изменения видны после последнего пункта из "Должно быть".

Как я это пытаюсь сделать:

1. В коде создал объекты (3) внутри которых есть коллекция точек ObservableCollection
2. Эти три объекта привязал к графикам через DataContext
3. В XAML поставил графики SfChart (Syncfusion), в них создал SplineSeries и их ItemSource привязал к коллеции нужного объекта.
4. В коде, после нажатия на запуск теста, начинается цикл for внутри которого посылаются данные, получаются статусы, находятся нужны точки для данного этапа и потом эти точки отображаются на графике (этого не происходит).
5. Как я уже писал выше, после всей этой котовасии, графики должны поменять названия и показать вычесленные параметры.

Что я делаю не так? Я не прошу писать за меня код, я прошу объяснить как правильно писать все эти изменения интерфейса.
К сожалению не могу выставить тут примеры кода (низзя).
Огромно спасибо всем, кто попытается помочь!
Если вопрос некорректно задан - уберу.

Comment: «4. В коде, после нажатия на запуск теста, начинается цикл for внутри которого посылаются данные, получаются статусы, находятся нужны точки для данного этапа и потом эти точки отображаются на графике (этого не происходит).» — вот это и неправильно, вы блокируете UI-поток. Выгружайте обработку в другой поток.

Comment: @VladD - Как это сделать? Весь цикл надо в другой поток?

Comment: Ага. Весь. Читайте здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615113/10105 (только вместо `Sleep` у вас длинные вычисления).

Comment: Нужно запускать всю логику в отдельном потоке, чтобы не тормозить ГУЙ,

Comment: @Michael: Смотрите особенно пример с `ParseBigFile`.

Comment: @VladD Так я пробовал. Это хорошо, но зачем мне использовать await Task.Delay? Я хочу показать пользователю точку сразу после ее получения, а не ждать еще какое-то время. Или я не правильно подхожу?

Comment: @VladD - О!! Так может получиться!!

Comment: @VladD - а где можно про все это почитать? Интерактивные курсты и т.д.? Пришел в WPF из Винформс и там правда пользовался таймером для таких вещей :))

Comment: @VladD - по указанной ссылке я не понял как же я обновляю график на каждой итерации :( Надо же каждую новую точку добавлять к коллекции. Будет ли обновлятся график, если я из фонового процесса добавлю новую точку в коллекцию? Если например эту коллецкию определю таким образом: BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите. Проблема в пункте 4 — «В коде, после нажатия на запуск теста, начинается цикл for внутри которого посылаются данные, получаются статусы, находятся нужны точки для данного этапа и потом эти точки отображаются на графике». Почему это неправильно, написано здесь: [Почему Thread.Sleep ведёт себя неправильно? Как мне сделать задержку или длинные вычисления в графической программе?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615113/10105)

Теперь о том, как же это починить. Ваша функция, работающая с вычислениями в фоновом потоке, должна доставлять результаты в главный поток. Есть много методов сделать это, проще всего, наверное, через `IProgress`.

Давайте определим структуру данных, описывающую новую точку графика:

```
class ComputedPoint
{
    public double X, Y;
    // тут ещё какие-то данные
}
```

Теперь наше вычисление будет выглядеть так:

```
void Compute(int param1, double param2, IProgress<ComputedPoint> progress)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < param1; i++)
    {
        // вычисляете следующую точку
        progress.Report(new ComputedPoint() { X = 5, Y = computedValue };
    }
}
```

И запускаете его так:

```
Progress<ComputedPoint> p = new Progress<ComputedPoint>(OnNewPoint);
await Task.Run(() => Compute(100, 0.5, p));
```

Метод `OnNewPoint` будет вызван в нужном потоке, об этом позаботится класс `Progress<T>`.

В самом методе `ComputedPoint` вы добавляете точку куда нужно:

```
void OnNewPoint(ComputedPoint pt)
{
    // тут добавляете точку в коллекцию, к которой у вас привязка
}
```

---

Позаботьтесь, чтобы новые точки не приходили слишком часто, иначе ваше приложение будет всё равно подвисать. Если точки вычисляются слишком быстро, передавайте их в UI пачками по нескольку (например, 100) штук.

Comment: Связанные вопросы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/588764/10105, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/577871/10105.

Comment: Круто!! Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Michael: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло!