# Создать объект и его расчеты в другом потоке

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность, циклы

Есть приложение на `WPF`. В итоге при нажатии кнопки необходимо создать объект другого класса и в нем произвести расчеты, там цикл из 1000 итераций. Но, когда происходят эти расчеты, необходимо в режиме реального времени после каждой итерации в `RichTextBox` записывать результаты расчета и чтобы я мог видеть эти результаты в данный момент, а не пока функция цикла завершится и вернется контроль в основной поток. Как это можно сделать?

P.s. также, если я создам параллельно второй поток с расчетами, мне необходимо будет записывать данные в основной поток, как это тоже связать? С помощью Invoke, но как именно реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Твое решение не подойдет для MVVM приложения, которое удобнее поддерживать. Что я предлагаю

Тут мы вяжем ViewModel к View:

```
<Window x:Class="TestWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWPF"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Margin="0 0 0 10"/>
        <Button Content="Start" Command="{Binding ButtonClickCommand}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Привязываем ViewModel к DataContext

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

Сам ViewModel. В конструкторе то, что хочешь выполнить в потоках

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void RaiseOnProprtyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = null)
            => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        #endregion

        #region Поля
        private string _Text { get; set; }
        public string Text
        {
            get => _Text;
            set { _Text = value; RaiseOnProprtyChanged(); }
        }

        ICommand _ButtonClickCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand ButtonClickCommand
        {
            get => _ButtonClickCommand;
            set { _ButtonClickCommand = value; RaiseOnProprtyChanged(); }
        }
        #endregion

        public ViewModel()
        {
            ButtonClickCommand = new SimpleCommand(async param =>
            {
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    var iter = new List<int>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) iter.Add(i);

                    Parallel.ForEach(iter, el =>
                        {
                            Text = el.ToString();
                        });
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

И SimpleCommand

```
public class SimpleCommand : ICommand
{
    #region Поля
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    private readonly Action<object> _exec;
    private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExec;
    #endregion

    #region Конструктор
    public SimpleCommand(Action<object> exec, Func<object, bool> canExec = null)
    {
        if (exec is null) throw new ArgumentNullException("exec is null");

        _exec = exec;
        _canExec = canExec;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Методы
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_canExec is null) return true;
        return _canExec(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter) => _exec?.Invoke(parameter); 
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В итоге решил свою проблему таким образом :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Thread gg = new Thread(ss);
        gg.Start();
    }

    void ss()
    {
        Optimization opt = new Optimization(this);
        opt.Start();
    }
```

Но, возможно, есть более лаконичный способ ;)
Доступ к объекту осуществил так :

```
 wnd.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(delegate { wnd.richTextBox.AppendText("Началась новая итерация"); }));
```

Comment: Может, лучше [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/577871)?

Comment: @Vlad у вас конечно более профессионально написано, пока я пишу шаблон, чтобы всё работало, как буду прибегать к лаконичности и производительности, обязательно изучу ваш пример) Спасибо)